# How to use Entity Framework and code-first in WebApi to create a database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Newbie here.

**Problem:**

When I open the SQL Server Object explorer from the menu in VS2017, I did not find my database called `UserRegistryDB`.

Please help. I did the following.

1. I have installed SQL Server 2017 EXPRESS
2. I add Entity Framework to reference in the project.
3. I have created a class `UserDBContext.cs` in the `Model` folder

   ```
   public class UserDBContext : DbContext
   {      
       public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. I have added a model class in `Model` folder

   ```
   public class User
   {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string emailID { get; set; }
           public string AppName { get; set; }
           public string SessionToken { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. I have added this in the `web.config`:

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="UserDBContext"
            connectionString="server=.; database= UserRegistryDB; integrated security = true;"
            providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
     </connectionStrings>
   ```
6. I build my project and run it; there are no compilation error, build success.

I need help with the question:

what are the differences in connection string that using server =. , server=(local) ? or server=(localdb)

```
connectionString="server=. ; database= UserRegistryDB; integrated security = true;"

connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably worth reading the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

`.` and `(local)` refer to the installed **default** instance - the instance without any specific instance name (will be shown in SQL Server Configuration Manager as `MSSQLSERVER`). This can be any edition of SQL Server - Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise, Developer etc.

`(localdb)` refers to an installed SQL Server **Express LocalDB** instance - that's a developer-oriented version of SQL Server Express that isn't installed as a Windows Service and runs all the time, but instead only starts up and runs while your Visual Studio or your application is running

Comment: I would like to know is there any thing i did wrong? What I need to do so I can create the Database and the table. I need  your help.